# show that $\mu$ is countably monotone if and only if $\mu^*$ is an extension of $\mu$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

> Let $\mathbf{S}$ be a collection of subsets of a set $\mathbf{X}$ and
>   $\mu : \mathbf{S} \to [0,\infty]$ is a set function. Show that $\mu$ is
>   countably monotone if and only if $\mu^*$ is an extension of $\mu$.
>   (From Royden Fitpatrick Ch17.29)

For the reverse direction, assume $\mu^*$ is the extension of $\mu$. In other words, $\mu^*$ restricted to $\mathbf{S}$ equals $\mu$.

Since the outer measure $\mu^*$ satisfies $\mu^*$($\varnothing$) = $0$ and countable monotonicity, then $\mu$ being the restirction of $\mu^*$ to $\mathbf{S}$ also satisfies the above properties.

For the forward direction, I am not sure how showing a set function with countable monotonicity would imply the outer measure is an extension of itself.

Edit: The [proof](http://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5210/Beamer-Proofs/Proofs-17-5-print.pdf) for the forward direction. Thanks Dr. Bob Gardnerr

Comment: Is $\textbf{S}$ a $\sigma$-ring, an algebra, a $\sigma$-algebra, or simply a collection of subsets of $X$? If it is only a collection, how can $\mu$ be countably monotone if the union is not required to be in $S$? I do not have the book at hand.

Comment: $\mathbf{S}$ is just given as a collection of subsets of $\mathbf{X}$ in the book. No other criterion were given.